# Ajax Ad Providers approved by Facebook

Tags: ajax, facebook, gwt

I'm developing a Facebook Application (using GWT & Java) which will be running within the FB canvas. My application is completely ajax-based -- no page refreshes, therefore I'm looking to use an Ads Provider with the following characteristics:

1. Approved by Facebook
2. Allows ajax-based refreshes of the ads (e.g. adSense doesn't allow that for now)
3. Possibly has a GWT implementation of their Ads API

Any help is appreciated!

P.S. 
Providing the list of the Approved Ad Providers isn't enough -- there are too many of them:
https://developers.facebook.com/adproviders/